my pipeline is not working due to testDebugUnitTest failed
I'm still working on my pipeline and I'm trying to integrate SonarQube to it
steps:
- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'ElemetnX'
    scannerMode: 'Other'
    extraProperties: |
      # Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner,
      # Put one key=value per line, example:
      # sonar.exclusions=**/*.bin
      sonar.projectKey=elementx_elementx_c8fe3377-ef93-4546-a899-36eef3ea9c1b
      sonar.projectName=elementx

- script: |
    java -version
    wget https://builds.openlogic.com/downloadJDK/openlogic-openjdk/17.0.10+7/openlogic-openjdk-17.0.10+7-linux-x64.tar.gz -O JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz
    tree
  displayName: Download JDK17

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/JAVA_HOME_17/X64'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
    createExtractDirectory: false

- script: |
    java -version
    echo Environment Variable JAVA_HOME_17_X64 is $(JAVA_HOME_17_X64)
    tree $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)
  displayName: Check JDK version

- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tasks: 'build'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17' # Use pre-installed JAVA17
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
    sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '2.6.1'
    spotBugsAnalysis: false

- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

The problem I'm confronting now is that the build doesn't successfully work due to this failed test https://dev.azure.com/nadamajd/elementx/_build/results?buildId=742&view=logs&j=12f1170f-54f2-53f3-20dd-22fc7dff55f9&t=ea098990-53e4-52aa-5a84-5ead7c5f17f2&l=11464
Is there anyways to solve this problem?

If the tests are failing you should investigate why and fix them

You probably need the SonarQubeAnalyze@5 task as well, before publishing the analysis.

The gradle task has logic to perform the analysis.

I tried it and i got this warning ##[warning][SQ] When using Maven or Gradle, don't use the analyze task but instead tick the 'SonarQube' option in the Maven/Gradle task to run the scanner as part of the build. but no result @RuiJarimba

There is nothing wrong. Failing tests should break the build. This should sound the alarm that someone on the team has introduced something that is broken and requires immediate attention. It is not a recommended practice to suppress or ignore these failures.
If the tests are working correctly on all the developer's machines, it suggests one of the following:

The build environment is significantly different than the developers environment and they are unable to reproduce the problem. For example, Windows versus Linux. It's possible that the code is actually broken and the developer's aren't aware.

The tests have environmental dependencies that aren't present in the build environment, or the test execution is non-deterministic and the tests either need to run in a specific order (which is bad) or the application state has interdependencies and shared state (which is also bad)


Review the tests with the development team to determine if the tests are false-negatives and which action to take (eg remove the tests versus fix the tests)
Regarding how Azure Pipelines work:

All tasks in the pipeline support a condition. If a task does not specify a condition, it defaults to succeeded() which means the task requires the previous task to be successful.
When an uncaught error occurs in a pipeline, it treats the pipeline as 'failed' and any subsequent task that depends on this task is skipped.
If you have tasks that you want to always run, regardless of the previous outcome you can set an appropriate condition.

To have your SonarQube task run regardless if the Gradle@3 task failed, add the following:
- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'


Thank you @bryanbcook for clarification. I have updated it but I received this message ##[warning]No analyses found in this build! Please check your build configuration. and nothing showed up on sonarqube

You are likely missing configuration settings in the prepare task or the report is being generated somewhere that the publish task cannot locate. https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/devops-platform-integration/azure-devops-integration/#using-the-prepare-analysis-configuration-task

can you show me exactly how am I supposed to modify the pipeline? @bryanbcook
